# Using AngularJs with app manifest doesn't load default state

Tags: angularjs, android-manifest

I'm trying to use App Manifest on my android mobile phone with my AngularJs/Ui-router application, it's working, but not as expected.

When I start the WebApp, it starts on the index.html, but not with the default route activate. For example, it shows up the menu, and some html I have on my index file, but it doesn't navigate to the homepage, where I have other html to build the page.

If after the initial load I start navigating with the menu, everything works as expected, I can call the states, request data from the server, etc... Is just the first load that is not working. How can I fix this?

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Web App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon-64.png",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 1.0
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#8d2515",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `"start_url"`. This should most likely be set to `"./"`.

This should be the relative URL of your default route.

Comment: Do you mean something like `./Welcome` or whatever my `url` name is defined on the ui-router, right? Because using just `./` didn't worked, but defining the name now is working. Thanks

Comment: Yep. Glad I could help.